What is replacement for ContentCatalogData.InternalIds in Addressables?
After I updated to Unity 6, it automatically updates my Addressables package to the latest version. The problem, that it breaks backward compatibility and property ContentCatalogData.InternalIds was removed.
What can I use instead of ContentCatalogData.InternalIds to keep my program work?
P.S. I use ContentCatalogData.InternalIds to determine what bundles are included to the catalog embedded in build and redirect loading path with Addressables.InternalIdTransformFunc to take these bundles from build storage, but not download them from server.
